# Linear pseudo random generation using same System.Random algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, random

Are there any way to predict some number of the Random class without going through a loop of rnd.NextDouble()?

i am using this code now:

```
Random rnd = new Random(SOME_STATIC_SEED);

//I need to get the 1000000'th random number:
for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) 
//I need to avoid this loop and get the result in a linear time!
{
      rnd.NextDouble();
}
double iNeedThisNumber = rnd.NextDouble();
```

How can i get it without the loop? i need the same exact number given using the algorithm of System.Random class of .Net!

---

Allegedly solved:

This is my code!!

```
public static ulong GetNumberFromSequence(int seq) 
{ 
    Random rnd = new Random(seq); 
    return (ulong)(rnd.NextDouble() * 99999999999999) ^ (ulong)seq; 
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using System.Random .Net class to generate pseudo-random sequence, but when i tried to do this i was forced to loop through all previous numbers to get the corresponding random of some number, i need some algorithm to get this number without any loop in some linear complexity algorithm.

Comment: If you need a random number generator that has this property, you should just use a random number generator that has this property.

Comment: Why do you need the 1e6th number? This seems a problem best changed by re-asking the question. And btw, your loop runs in linear time.

Comment: I am sorry, not linear time but static time, I m so sorry!

Comment: It runs in constant time even. But that's following the pedantic definition. Anyway since both the seed and the loopcount are constants here, why not just save the internal state of the Random once and then use that? Or if they are variable, please mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

Use the seed for the desired index in the random-number generator, and then pick the first generated number.

```
Random rnd = new Random(required_index_as_seed).Next();
double iNeedThisNumber = rnd.NextDouble();
```

Comment: Did you test this before posting?

Comment: This is my code!!
    public static ulong GetNumberFromSequence(int seq)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random(seq);
        return (ulong)(rnd.NextDouble() * 99999999999999) ^ (ulong)seq;
    }

Comment: Pleaaaaaaase tell me, what is the secret of the number 47995853??? i am facing it wherever i go with pseudo random generation!!! an out of memory exception is thrown when i arrive to it, I've used variations of algorithms and the same number facing me!

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser... Is this a new-years prank?

Answer (score 0):

You can either precalculate the values for a given seed and cache them in a list or a database, or use an alternative pseudo-random number generator that can generate index values in linear time.